# Hive table validation using script

Tags: hive

I have an hive table ( t1)
I validate t1 with a script (s1.sql)
the result is stored in another hive table (t2)

now based on the number of records in t1 and t2, there is a condition.

if the condition is satisfied, t2 is analysed with another script(s2.sql)
if not, no analysis is done. 
I'm executing these in bash. 
how to perform this???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, in your shell script, you'll do something like:

```
foo=$(hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; select count(*) from t1;")
bar=$(hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; select count(*) from t2;")
if (($foo > $bar)); then
#or whatever your comparison is
hive -e <your next query>
else...
fi
```

If you'd prefer, you can put the individual queries in separate hql files and call them with `hive -f <pathtofile/file>`

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted..  
But I'm getting 

"ParseException line 1.0 cannot recognize input near 'f' '=' '$' "

when storing value in variables foo and bar.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?  If you are, post your first line and we'll see what's going on.  Also, I left the $ off the variable names in the if statement.